# IF Statement and not in select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, informix

The Informix it works, how to do like this in Oracle?

```
IF (uzel NOT IN (SELECT a.uzel FROM user_setup.menu a WHERE a.vetka <> a.uzel
                             AND a.vetka IN (SELECT vetka FROM user_setup.param_menu)))
          THEN
             --;
          END IF;
```

Comment: Have you tried doing that in oracle?as it is.

Comment: Yes. [Error] PLS-00405 (33: 28): PLS-00405: subquery is not allowed in this context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
  temp NUMBER;
  v_uzel user_setup.menu.uzel%TYPE;
BEGIN    
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  INTO temp
  FROM dual
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT A.uzel 
                FROM user_setup.menu A 
                WHERE A.vetka <> A.uzel
                AND A.uzel = v_uzel
                AND A.vetka IN (SELECT vetka FROM user_setup.param_menu));


  IF temp < 1 THEN
    -- code here 

  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: This is right. You can't use a SQL query directly in a PL/SQL expression. You need to store its result in a variable first.

Comment: as an aside, I assume that `uzel` is a variable in the code, and it's also a column in the menu table. If you're going to use the variable in the SQL statement, make sure it has a different name to any of the column names in the table(s), as the query will most likely assume you're talking about the column, not the variable.

Comment: I mentioned that more for the OP's benefit, but it's good that you changed your answer too *{:-)

Comment: Don't you need `select count(*)`? Otherwise when the condition is not met, a No Data Found error will be raised?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you need to use a different approach:

```
DECLARE
   usel1 <specify here the data type for the usel>;
BEGIN

  SELECT a.uzel INTO usel1 
  FROM user_setup.menu a 
  WHERE a.vetka <> a.uzel AND a.usel = uzel
   AND a.vetka IN (SELECT vetka FROM user_setup.param_menu))

   -- this means the record is found.

EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     -- do other processing here
END;
```

Comment: [Error] PLS-00103 (32: 21): PLS-00103: Met symbol "EXISTS" while the expected one of the following: in like like2 like4 likec between member submultiset